set environment variables for forkedSpringBootRun with SpringDoc
Is there a way to set environment variables for SpringDoc's forkedSpringBootRun task? SpringDoc can't start my application because a bunch of environment variables are expected but are missing.
I've tried adding the following to my build.gradle:
forkedSpringBootRun {
    environment AWS_REGION: 'ap-southeast-2'
    environment ENVIRONMENT: 'unittest'
}

But for whatever reason they're not feeding through to forkedSpringBootRun
